# Implode vs Manually Concatenante Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, oop

So, I have a class that has to assemble a string from member variables. I can think of three ways to do it, but I'm not sure which is more inline with the common way to do such or how to test which is fastest.

**Option 1** is to implode an array with all the data in it,

**Option 2** is use array_walk over the array and pass an anonymous function that assembles it into a string

**Option 3** is to manually concatenate the string.

Comment: What is the final purpose of this string that is to be assembled? Seems like it all comes down to preference. I'd imagine manually concatenating the string would be the fastest since it has less overhead in calling functions. (Could be wrong O_o).

Comment: Option 1 will fit most scenarios you will encounter. Manually concatenating a string is usually messy and harder to read, I always try to avoid it. I have never used `array_walk` to ever build a string either.

Comment: @Ye. It is being written to a file. The data, something like 150 variables, has to be in a specific order.

Comment: @nobrandheroes It might be a bit messy with 150 variables to use manual concatenation like SamV said above. Would advise implode().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some rules to live by when screwing with arrays:

1. Do the bare minimum required.

   - If you already have an `array`, use built in functions that accept `array`.  I.E. `implode`.
2. Exploit the engine.

   - If you have a `Traversable` or `ArrayAccess`, which can be reduced to an `array`, use `implode` only if the array itself isn't going to be modified.
3. If all else fails.

   - If you cannot reduce an object to an array, or if you need to perform modifications of said object by repeated copying into a standard array, it is better to perform the manipulation on the object itself.

Of course, this is just how I treat them when I get paranoid over memory.